# executor.invokeAll() doesn't finish execution

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream, executorservice

So I'm trying to implement some kind of fork on a "toy language". It's like implementing my own compiler. So when the user does a fork, my program it's supposed to start/simulate some threading. 
In my code, I prepare the callables and then I start the execution of the callables but when I use invokeAll my program doesn't terminate, it just doesn't do anything.

I ran the code through debug and it just stops the debugging when I get to invokeAll() but it doesn't terminate or throw error or anything ( I have the invoke inside a try-catch ). I tried with fixed threading pool too. It doesn't do anything

Some code:

```
// preparing the callables
java.util.List<Callable<MyClass>> callList = prgll.stream()
        .map(p -> (Callable<MyClass>) () -> {
    return p.oneStep(); //a method from my class
}).collect(Collectors.toList());

//start the execution of the callables
//it should return the list of new created threads
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
java.util.List<MyClass> fff;
try {
    fff = executor.invokeAll(callList).stream() // here my program gets blocked but not all the time, only when I call use myFork class
    .map(future-> {
        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new CustomException("Error in onestepforall" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }).filter(p->p != null).collect(Collectors.toList());

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new CustomException("Error while trying executor" +e.getMessage());
}
```

Can I debug this to get deeper inside my code to see exactly why invokeAll stays on stand-by?

I also tried changing from a new SingleThread to a fixed pool but it still didn't do anything.

Comment: Do you ever call `shutdown()` on your ExecutorService after adding all tasks?

Comment: Yea I tried doing that and nothing happened. The problem persisted

Comment: Continue simplifying the code and the problem until you can isolate the problem, is about all I can recommend.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to simplify the program.

Comment: can you add timeout in future.get() call? I suspect that your individual tasks are taking more time.

Comment: Also, try a *cached* thread pool.  Its possible that, if any tasks wait for the completion of another, there are not enough threads in the pool, which can lead to deadlock (See "Pool-induced deadlock" in JCiP.)  Using a cached thread pool with no thread limit will eliminate this as a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

`invokeAll()` is a blocking method, i.e. it waits until all futures have completed.

`.map` the list of callables through the executor's `submit()` instead if you want async task submission.

If your question is why the tasks don't complete then you don't want to debug the thread submitting to the executor but the spawned thread(s) since the tasks are executed on a separate thread. Instead of using a breakpoint you can simply suspend the whole JVM with the attached debugger and then look at individual threads.

Comment: How do you suspend the JVM with the debugger?

Comment: that is specific to the individual debugger's UI. I suggest either googling it, consulting the manual or making a separate question.

Comment: Or, force a thread dump (kill -3 on unix) to see what all the threads are doing. Look for threads with oneStep() on its stack trace, and that may point you to why your tasks are not completing.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and apparently you can't suspend the JVm with the debug.

Comment: it's trivial with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. p.oneStep() was never completing for fork because there was an infinite loop inside the method. I got rid of it and everything else works fine.